# Uploading automatically Wordpress?

Tags: ios, database, wordpress

I want my website to automatically update when someone adds an app.
Some examples:
http://iphoneapp-promocodes.com
http://www.appshots.net/

I want to make it so someone can click add app and then they put there iTunes app url in the box and it will automatically be added to my website.

How Can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The key would be to get a connection to the database in wich the apps are stored from there you should write a script wich return every object a table holds with the corresponding properties.

Although I do not recommend you use wordpress for this, try make your custom php script or try ruby on rails wich makes these kinds of things possible in minutes.

Although if the website has an API you can just use its functions to use their records.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for the iTunes Affiliate Program.  Its home page (http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/) says:

> The iTunes, App Store, iBookstore, and Mac App Store Affiliate Program
>   provides a unique way for your website or app to link to millions of
>   songs and thousands of apps — as well as books, Hollywood movies, TV
>   shows, music videos, games, audiobooks, and podcasts.

They have an API for getting specific information.